# How to add order in processing if user is returning using?

Tags: wordpress

I have been using the “Cash on Delivery” payment method in Woocommerce and added custom Order Status “COD” in Woocommerce. I have been using the following code to move orders to “COD” if the user selected the “COD” payment option.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cod_process_payment_order_status', 'change_cod_payment_order_status', 10, 2 );
function change_cod_payment_order_status( $order_status, $order ) {
   return 'cod';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to set the order status to processing if the user is a returned customer.

Let us assume returned customer means the user has already bought something from you.

```
function is_order_has_shipping_product( $order_id ) {
    if( ! $order_id ) return;
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items(); // Get All The Order Items
    $found = false;

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get The Item Product ID
        $product    = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $is_virtual = $product->is_virtual(); 


        if(!$is_virtual) {
            $found = true;
            break; // If not virtual then stop the loop
        }
    }


     return $found ;

}
```

The above function will check if an order has any product other than the virtual product.

```
    function is_returning_customer($user_id = null) {
    
    if( !$user_id ){
     $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    }

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order', // WC orders post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-completed', // Only orders with status "completed"
        'fields'      => 'ids'
    ) );

    $is_returning_customer = false;
    if( count( $customer_orders ) > 0){

        foreach($customer_orders as $order_id){

           $has_shipping_product =  is_order_has_shipping_product( $order_id );
           if($has_shipping_product){
                $is_returning_customer = true;
                break;
           }

        }
    }
   return $is_returning_customer;
}
```

So we can use the above function to determine the returning status. You can change the logic if you have any.
So now coming to the status change.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cod_process_payment_order_status', 'change_cod_payment_order_status', 10, 2 );
function change_cod_payment_order_status( $order_status, $order ) {

    $user_id               = $order->get_user_id();
    $is_returning_customer = is_returning_customer($user_id);

    if($is_returning_customer){
        return 'processing';
    }

    return 'cod';
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. If the user is a returned customer, the order should remain in the processing section instead of moving to COD section. Do I have to paste both the code in the function.php section?

Comment: Yes , You can paste the new function and replace the filter with the modified filter.  Please check the logic of returning customer it only check completed order.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again. Do I have to replace my code with the code you provided? And in the comment section you heve mentioned to check the logic of returning customers. What does that mean?

Comment: Yes,  You have to replace the code with mine. (Please take a backup of your code).

For `is_returning_customer` function. For me, if the user has a minimum one (1) completed order then I return the user as returning customer. This function will return false if the user has only processing, cancelled, pending payment orders etc. 

Fill free to comment.

Comment: Thanks. On my WooCommerce, I sell two kinds of products. one is virtual and another one is shipment products. If the user has purchased virtual before, and then (same day or another day) placed an order of shipment products, the order should not move to processing section. But if the user is ordering shipment products again, then the order should move to the processing section, otherwise, it should remain in the COD section.

Comment: It's not clear from your comment. When should I take the user as a returning customer?
What is the final status of an order in your WooCommerce?  


Can you please describe 'What is returning customer ' according to you?

Comment: Let me clear. As we all know that woocommerce has two kinds of products, one is virtal and another one is shipping. If a user purchased a virtual product, the user will be counted as a returning user. But I don't want to count a user as a returning user if their first order was virtual. I want to count a user as returning user if they has purchased a product that we ship.

Comment: Hi, I will help you but has some confusion. 
You said if a user purchased a virtual product the user will be counted as a returning customer and also if they purchased a shipping product.  http://prntscr.com/wid8qx

So the user must have one shipping product is their previous order (Order status can be anything) correct? 

is it possible to place an order with 2 types of product? (virtual and shipping)

Comment: I tested the code on my website and according to your code, even if a user purchased a virtual product, the user counts as a returning user. The user must have one shipping product in their previous order. But the previous order status must be completed.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted this line http://prntscr.com/wiewjw
I will update the code asap.

Comment: Thanks. The user must have one shipping product in their previous order and that shipping product must be completed.